# If any checkbox is checked then certain textboxes will be enabled

Tags: vb.net

In private sub form1_loader:

```
    For each obj as object in Me.Controls

            If TypeOf obj is windows.forms.textbox then

                    Directcast(obj, windows.forms.textbox).enabled = false

            End if

    Next
```

But I also wanted to have some certain textboxes to be enabled if any checkbox has been checked (even if there's only one checked)

And disable if none of the checkboxes are checked.

I am not familiar in coding and it's my first time for class activity so I don't know a lot.

Would there be a way for this one or should I manually code for every private sub of checkboxes?

Answer (score 3):

This will enable three specific `TextBoxes` if and only if at least one of three specific `CheckBoxes` are checked:

```vb
Dim anyCheckBoxChecked = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}.Any(Function(cb) cb.Checked)

For Each tb In {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    tb.Enabled = anyCheckBoxChecked
Next
```

You can extend that to any set of either type of control, e.g. all controls of that type in a specific container:

```vb
Dim anyCheckBoxChecked = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Any(Function(cb) cb.Checked)

For Each tb In Panel2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox3)()
    tb.Enabled = anyCheckBoxChecked
Next
```